# Rsync system() execution in Perl fails randomly with protocol error

Tags: linux, perl, rsync, centos6, mod-perl

We commonly call `rsync` in (Mod)Perl (and PHP) and haven't run into too many issues but we are running into an occassional protocol error when running a command that when run on a subsequent request goes through fine. The funny thing is even if I retry in code, for the same http request, it will fail every time, but if you make another http request it will likely succeed.

Code looks like this:

```
$cmd = sprintf('rsync -auvvv --rsync-path="rsync --log-file=/tmp/ui-rsync.log" %s %s', "$fromDir/$fromBase/", "$path/$toBase/");
$exitCode = system($cmd);
```

The --rsync-path argument was added in there later for debugging. It was unhelpful. It fails either way.

The errors look like this:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

or like this:

```
unexpected tag 93 [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(1134) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

I debug the actual generated commands and I can run them by-hand fine.

The http user can run the commands fine.

Again, a programmatic retry *never* works, but a manually retry (hitting the same http endpoint that triggers it), works almost always.

Appreciate any help as this has been driving us crazy for...a long time, with many fixes tried.

Comment: Can you get any `rsync` to work programmatically? Any issues with (programmatic) `ssh` logins, garbage in output, etc?

Comment: Thoughts: Add `-e 'ssh -v'` for hopefully more detail on `ssh`; Try to look into remote's `rsync` daemon log; Try to print the `$cmd` and copy-paste it to terminal (if you haven't); An [rsync page](https://rsync.samba.org/issues.html) shows a debugging shell script to install on then remote system

Comment: @zdim Yes, these same programmatic rsync commands works programmatically on 50%+ of executions. Just sometimes they don't.

Comment: @zdim Thanks, I'll try the -e idea

Comment: @zdim I tried adding in -e 'ssh -v' and while it's nice verbose output it didn't provide me any clues about how to diagnose the issue. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change system() to backticks. Seriously. I don't know why it works.

The change is literally this:

```
# BAD:
$exitCode = system($cmd);
# GOOD:
`$cmd`;
```

If I had to guess I'd say there's some subtle difference with how the shell is being initialized, maybe some environment variables or memory locations not being cleaned properly. I really don't know, though.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a real [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), you could retry rsync maybe three times with some sleep between:

```
for my $n (1..3){
   my $exitCode = system($cmd);
   my_log_sub("SUCCESS: rsync succeded on try $n") + last if $exitCode==0;
   my_log_sub("ERROR: rsync $n of 3 failed: $cmd $! $?");
   sleep(1) if $n<3;
}
```

Have you checked your local and remote logs? Try `sudo ls -rtl /var/log/` or `sudo ls -rtl /var/log/httpd/` right after a fail and `tail -f /var/log/one_of_the_newest_logs` while retrying.

Have you checked if the remote disk is full or if the directory exists? Firewall issue? Remote and local rsync or ssh versions are (very) different? (although I guess that should show a clearer error message)

Comment: It's not technically a heisenbug, it's just randomly failing. Yes, I've put in retries. The thing I find odd is when it fails and retries it will *always* fail but you can run it on a subsequent request and it works. I did check local and remote logs, nothing that I could identify that would highlight the root cause. I can run the command by hand and it works so yes there's enough disk space, directories exist, remote and local ssh versions are the same. Thanks for the advice.